# Flutter : How to launch the Google Map app with "directions" to a predefined location?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

in my flutter code, I am launching Google Maps app with a predefined location, on a button click. Below is the code

```
 _launchMaps(double lat, double lon) async {
  String googleUrl =
    'comgooglemaps://?center=${lat},${lon}';
  String appleUrl =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lon';
  if (await canLaunch("comgooglemaps://")) {
    print('launching com googleUrl');
    await launch(googleUrl);
  } else if (await canLaunch(appleUrl)) {
    print('launching apple url');
    await launch(appleUrl);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch url';
  }
}
```

In iOS, I did add the following lines to the **info.plist** file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>googlechromes</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>
```

In `Android`, when I click on the button I get the google maps opened, and I can clearly see the "Directions" button where I can click and start navigating. example below

[image]

In iOS I get the Google Map opened, the location is pointed in marker, but I don't get the "Directions" button or anything like that so I can start navigating. how can I fix this?

Comment: As per the [Maps URLs documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action), you can launch request directions and launch Google Maps with the results by using the URL:  `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @PeakGen have you achieved any result?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#directions), you need to define the starting point lat/long and end point lat/long on the URL to prompt for a direction navigation. The URL should look similar to:

`comgooglemaps://?saddr={LAT},{LONG}&daddr={LAT},{LONG}&directionsmode=driving`

Answer (score 1):

```
    //open google map & apple map app

String appleUrl = 'https://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=$lat,$lon&directionsmode=driving';
String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lon';


if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await canLaunch(appleUrl)) {
    await launch(appleUrl);
  } else {
    if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
      await launch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }
} else {
  if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
    await launch(googleUrl);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not open the map.';
  }
}
```

Also:

```
// Android
var url = 'geo:$latitude,$longitude';
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS
  String query = Uri.encodeComponent(address);
  url = 'https://maps.apple.com/?q=$query';
}
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the code that works with url_launcher 6.1.12:

```
String appleUrl = 'https://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=$lat,$lon&directionsmode=driving';
String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lon';

Uri appleUri = Uri.parse(appleUrl);
Uri googleUri =  Uri.parse(googleUrl);

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(appleUri)) {
    await launchUrl(appleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  } else {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(googleUri)) {
      await launchUrl(googleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }
  }
} else {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(googleUri)) {
    await launchUrl(googleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
}
```